# Error de exclusión en proyeccion de query en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Tengo una duda y es que yo estoy aplicando la proyección sólo con la parte de la proyección y no el `query`, por ejemplo:

```js
 db.empleados.find({},{nombre: 1, apellido: 0})
```

Sin embargo, me sale un error, no se si estoy usando la sintaxis bien o algo asi pero me dice esto:

```js
error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot do exclusion on field apellido in inclusion projection",
        "code" : 31254,
        "codeName" : "Location31254"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cuando usas un valor `1` indicando *inclusión* del campo `nombre` en tu proyección, todas las propiedades restantes (excepto `_id`) se sobreentienden en `0` (*exclusión*). Es por ello el mensaje de error, ya que estás indicando a la vez un valor de inclusión sobre `nombre` y uno de exclusión sobre `apellido`, lo cual no es correcto.

Esto quiere decir que tu proyección debe escribirse sólo en términos de inclusión o sólo en términos de exclusión. Por ejemplo:

```js
// inclusión
db.empleados.find({},{nombre: 1});  // incluye sólo nombre y _id

// exclusión
db.empleados.find({},{apellido: 0});  // excluye sólo apellido
```

La única excepción a esta regla es sobre el campo `_id` que siempre es devuelto (siempre se incluye en la respuesta) a menos que se indique lo contrario explícitamente en la proyección:

```js
// inclusión (excluye _id y el resto de campos) 
db.empleados.find({},{nombre: 1, _id: 0});  // incluye sólo nombre

// exclusión (excluye apellido y _id)
db.empleados.find({},{apellido: 0, _id: 0});  // excluye sólo apellido y _id
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Al parecer falta hacer hincapié en el hecho de que no se puede mezclar una proyección de inclusión con una de exclusión. Y es que muchos tutoriales no dejan claro este concepto.

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente documento almacenado en la colección `users` de mi base de datos:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("6176c88a48c86d4c72acc522"),
  nombre: "Mauricio",
  apellidos: "Contreras Canepa",
  email: "mauricio@email.com",
  edad: 0x69,
}
```

Si deseo obtener una lista de todos los documentos de mi colección `users` que incluyan sólo el campo `nombre`, la consulta sería la siguiente:

```js
db.users.find({},{ nombre: 1 });
```

El resultado de la consulta anterior sería:

```js
{
  ObjectId("6176c88a48c86d4c72acc522"),
  nombre: "Mauricio",
}
```

Como observamos trae, además del campo `nombre`, el campo `_id`.

La consulta anterior es una consulta de **inclusión**, estoy indicando explícitamente los campos que deseo obtener en el resultado.

No sólo puedes usar `1` y `0` como indicador, también puedes usar `true` y `false`. La siguiente consulta es totalmente válida y equivalente a la anterior:

```js
db.users.find({},{ nombre: true });
```

Ahora, si no deseamos incluir en el resultado de la consulta el campo `_id`, debemos excluirlo explícitamente. Este campo, siendo un campo especial de MongoDB siempre se considerará incluido en el resultado y es el único campo que puedo excluir explítamente en una proyección de inclusión. El resto de campos no puedo *excuirlos* explícitamente, ya que por defecto, todo campo no incluido en una proyección se considera excluido. Asimismo, todo campo que no sea excluido explícitamente en una proyección se considera incluido.

```js
db.users.find({},{ nombre: 1, _id: 0 });

// o usando true y false:

db.users.find({},{ nombre: true, _id: false });
```

Consideremos el escenario planteado en la pregunta y supongamos que el documento contiene los campos establecidos en este ejemplo. Si deseamos incluir el campo `nombre`, muy bien, usamos como proyección: `{ nombre: 1 }`. Eso indica que todos los campos restantes estarán excluidos (excepto el campo `_id`).

Ahora, supongamos que deseo excluir sólo el campo `apellidos`, entonces la proyección de exclusión será: `{ apellidos: 0 }`, y el resto de campos se considera incluido en la respuesta.

Por último, supongamos que quiero el campo `nombre` pero no quiero el campo `apellidos`, entonces se me ocurre escribir la siguiente proyección (errónea como ya hemos dicho): `{ nombre: 1, apellidos: 0 }`. ¿Qué pasa con el resto de campos? ¿Los incluyo? ¿Los excluyo? Si los incluyo ¿significa que la proyección de exclusión le gana a la inclusión? Si los excluyo ¿entonces es al contrario? ¿De qué manera puedo determinar lo que haré con el resto de campos?.

Es por ello que las proyecciones en MongoDB sólo se pueden escribir en términos de *inclusión* o de *exclusión*.

De todas formas, la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) es bastante específica al respecto:

Original:

> **Note**
>
> With the exception of the `_id` field, you cannot combine inclusion and exclusion statements in projection documents.

Traducción propia:

> **Nota**
>
> A excepción del campo `_id`, no se puede combinar sentencias de inclusión y exclusión en documentos de proyección.

Comment: Yo encontre este video que habla un poco de proyeccion a partir del minuto 5, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7MGxiVfje0&list=PLXXiznRYETLcJE_4U9qN2pysZOSYyL4Mh&index=18&ab_channel=RedesPlus, y al parecer se puede mezclar inclusion con exclusion y muestra los documentos correctos, sin embargo se le esta anadiendo un argumento a find() no se si eso sea la diferencia sin embargo lo probare y vere otros videos con respecto al tema

Comment: He visto el video que enlazas y en ningún momento combina inclusión y exclusión excepto cuando se trata del campo `_id`, que es lo que trato de argumentar en mi respuesta. La proyección de campos sólo puede ser de exclusión o sólo puede ser de inclusión, nunca puedes mezclar ambas. La única excepción es con el campo `_id`, que puedes excluirlo sin importar si la proyección es de inclusión o de exclusión. Saludos